# If the set $X$ is linearly independent in and does not span $V=\Bbb{R}^n$ then there is a $v\in V$ s.t. $\{v\}\cup X$ is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Show that if the set of linearly independent vectors ${X}$ does not span $\mathbb R^n$ then there exists a vector $v \in \mathbb R^n$ s.t. $\{v\} \cup X$ is linearly independent.

My shot at a proof for this by contraposition, let me know when I mess up:

let  $X \cup \{v\}$ be linearly dependent $\forall v \in \mathbb R^n$, then

$$\exists \alpha_1 , \dots,  \alpha_k\text{ s.t. }v=\alpha_1x_1 +\dots + \alpha_kx_k \forall v \in \mathbb R^n$$

thus by definition of span, $X$ spans $\mathbb R^n$

this is a contradiction of the original proposal, thus $\exists v \in R^n$ s.t. $v \cup X$ is linearly independent

Comment: Did you really mean $v\cup\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: nope! fixed it to read $v \cup X$

Comment: Or perhaps $\{v\}\cup X$.

Comment: you're correct Thomas, I've changed it. sorry guys, its early out here

Comment: If X itself is not linearly independent this statement is false.

Comment: Hamed, see above. I just edited it to state that it is linearly independent. thanks!

Comment: @CorranHorn, Is $X$ is linearly independent?

Comment: @BiswarupSaha yes, it's stated in the body of the question

Comment: By the way, you don't say what $v$ is in your proof. You need to find a $v,$ or show one exists.

Comment: [Very closely related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2820200/11619). Not nececssarily a dupe because this IS a proof verification request. I disprove of the practice to post alternative proofs as answers to such questions.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen unless someone is asking a truly novel question, in which case it's unclear to me why they'd be on this site to begin with, there are (almost) always multiple ways to prove a question.  My proof is different from the one that was already asked. I doubt anyone on here would recommend learning this stuff solely by copying down other's examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mostly correct, but incomplete.

You don't state what your $v$ is in the proof. You need to pick $v$ to be an element of $\mathbb R^n$ which is not in the span of $X$. (Thus, you are using one condition.)

You should also state why $\exists \alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k.$

If $X\cup\{v\}$ is linearly dependent, then $\exists \beta_0,\dots,\beta_k$ such that $$0=\beta_0 v + \beta_1 x_1+\dots+\beta_k x_k$$ with the $\beta_i$ not all zero.

But if $\beta_0=0$ then $X$ would be linearly dependent. So $\beta_0\neq 0$ and from there you can conclude that $\alpha_i=\frac{-\beta_i}{\beta_0}$ gives you:

$$v=\alpha_1 x_1+\cdots+\alpha_kx_k$$

showing $v\in \operatorname{Span}(X),$ which is a contradiction.

---

Indeed, this could be stated as a general lemma:

> **Lemma:** If $V$ is a vector space and $X\subset V$, 
>   then, for any $v\in V\setminus X$, $X\cup\{v\}$ is linearly independent if and only if $X$ is linearly independent and $v\notin\operatorname{Span}(X).$

This lemma is exactly why you can find $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k.$ Since $X$ is linearly independent, we have, by this lemma, if $X\cup \{v\}$ is linearly dependent, then $v\in\operatorname{Span}(X).$

Aside: This lemma assumes the definition that $\operatorname{Span}(\emptyset)=\{0\}.$

---

The question has two conditions:

1. $X$ is linearly independent
2. $X$ does not span $\mathbb R^n$

Without $(2),$ you cannot find $v.$

Without $(1),$ you cannot prove $X\cup\{v\}$ is linearly independent.

Your proof does not mention where you are using either condition.

Comment: does the statement, "$\exists \alpha_1 , ... , \alpha_k$ s.t. $\alpha_1x_1 +...+ \alpha_kx_k$" not flow directly from the definition of linear dependence? or is that explanation simply not sufficient for the proof?

Comment: Thomas Andrews, there is not mentioned that X is linearly independent

Comment: @BiswarupSaha Re-read the question, it has been edited.

Comment: @BiswarupSaha it's in the body of the question

Comment: @CorranHorn There are two possible definitions of linear dependence, but in either one, you still need to show this, though in some sense it is trivial. For example, why do you have to choose $v$ outside the span of $X$? Why is it important that $X$ is linearly independent? This is the step where you need both conditions.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews understood, thank you

Comment: I am responding to the proof verification request. I am filling in the missing details, and go extensively infto what is wrong with the proof give. @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Yes. I noticed. My intention was to post the comment under the OP. VERY SORRY about this. I have never had any complaints about YOUR approach to the site. Certain other users OTOH...

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is basically good, but there's no need to go that route.

Assume $X=\{v_1,\dots,v_r\}$ is linearly independent and let $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $v$ does not belong to the span of $X$.

Let $\alpha v+\alpha_1v_1+\dots+\alpha_rv_r=0$.

Suppose $\alpha\ne0$: then you get a contradiction (how?).

Therefore $\alpha=0$ and from here it is easy to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

The set $X$ does not generate $\Bbb{R}^n\implies\exists v\in\Bbb{R}^n\backslash X$ such that $v\notin \text{Span}(X)$.
I will show that $X\cup\{v\}$ is linearly independent.
Let us assume on contrary that, $X\cup\{v\}$ is linearly dependent. Then $\exists u_1, u_2, ..., u_k\in X\cup\{v\}$ scalers $a_1, a_2, ..., a_k\text{(not all zero)}\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $a_1 u_1+ a_2u_2+...+a_k u_k=0$
If $u_i\ne v\forall i\in \{1,2,..,k\}$, then it would imply $X$ is linearly dependent (because in that case $\{u_1, u_2, ...,u_k\}\subseteq X$).
So at least one of $u_i$'s must be $v$ (say $u_j)$.
We get $a_j v=a_1 u_1+...+a_{j-1} u_{j-1}+a_{j+1} u_{j+1}+...+a_k u_k$.
Not that $a_j\ne 0$(if not, suppose $a_j=0\implies a_1 u_1+...+a_{j-1} u_{j-1}+a_{j+1} u_{j+1}+...+a_k u_k=0\implies X$ is linearly dependent, contradiction).
So, $a_j^{-1}$ exists in $\Bbb{R}$, then $v=(a_j^{-1} a_1) u_1+...+(a_j^{-1} a_{j-1}) u_{j-1}+(a_j^{-1} a_{j+1})u_{j+1}+...+(a_j^{-1} a_k) u_k\implies v\in\text{Span}(X)$, contradiction.
So, we must have $X\cup\{v\}$ is linearly independent.